# Struct members double mutable borrow in Rust

Tags: rust

I found a situation in Rust when I cannot borrow mutably two different struct members, when the containing struct is wrapped in a Mutex:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::fmt::Debug;

struct A;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;

struct C {
    a: A,
    b: Box<dyn Debug>,
}

fn foo(a: &mut A, b: &mut dyn Debug) {

}

fn main() {
    let m = Mutex::new(C {
        a: A,
        b: Box::new(B)
    });

    let mut m = m.lock().unwrap();

    // error: cannot borrow `m` as mutable more than once at a time
    foo(&mut m.a, m.b.as_mut());
}
```

This does not happen if `m` is not wrapped in a Mutex. Is there a way to work around it (with only Sync + Send types)?

Comment: The duplicate answer applied to your code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a561964f5f2f866b42a22ec4c6547a4